# Which is best, "to access" or "of access"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When describing someone who is reclusive is it better to say:

> He was difficult **to** access.

or

> He was difficult **of** access.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: 68,700,000 Google hits for "hard to talk to".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I don't get the connexion. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - In my opinion this is a non-trivial question. Please feel free to comment on my answer, below.

Comment: @chasly Would you say of a reserved person 'He is difficult to access'? I'd use that for say the President.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I didn’t say it was necessarily non-trivial; but it shows no research effort.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Ah, I see. You are questioning the correctness of either saying in that context rather than the grammar of the phrases themselves. Good point.  I suppose one could claim that the President is difficult to access because he is *selectively* reticent. In that case it would work.  I'm sure he is reluctant to reveal his innermost feelings to any but a select few.

Comment: @chasly I think the edit is valid. The question then becomes meaningful, and I'd agree that the 'difficult to access' vs 'difficult of access' construction distinction is suitable for ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I don't disagree.

Answer (score 1):

> ..is it better to say "he was difficult to access" or "he was difficult of access"?

It depends what you mean by 'better'.

**He was difficult to access.**

In this case, 'to access' is the infinitive of the verb.  This way of writing it is common and idiomatic. For native speakers, it looks 'obvious'. However the grammatical structure is not so obvious. I am not even sure whether 'to access' is an adverbial phrase modifying 'was' or one modifying 'difficult.'

**He was difficult of access.**

Here, 'access' is a noun. This form occurs idiomatically in English in other phrases such as, *He was hard of hearing.*

**Answer**

The choice is one of idiom rather than logic or grammar. In past centuries the second version might have been acceptable. Today, only the first is used. You should say, **He was difficult to access.**

Comment: Good parallel example. At [Adjective + to infinitive vs. gerund](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132295/adjective-to-infinitive-vs-gerund) is further discussion and some varied examples of adjective complements (especially in Moss's answer).